# Can quotation marks be followed 's?

Tags: saxon-genitive

In academic publication, I must use inverted commas.

> "The fact that they had accepted the offer was sufficient to give rise to a binding contract, notwithstanding
> the fact that the plaintiffs were mistaken and that they pointed out their mistake to the defendants immediately and before the defendants had acted on it in any way."<sup>1</sup>

Presume I must write out "The fact that" like this.

> **Their** having "accepted the offer was sufficient to give rise to a binding contract, notwithstanding
> the fact that the plaintiffs were mistaken and that they pointed out their mistake to the defendants immediately and before the defendants had acted on it in any way."<sup>1</sup>

Now presume I must quote antecedent of **"Their"**, "[T]he defendants [who] clearly ought to be given leave to defend this action"<sup>2</sup>. Can I write this?

> **"[T]he defendants [who] clearly ought to be given leave to defend this action"**<sup>2</sup>`'s` having "accepted the offer was sufficient to give rise to a binding contract, notwithstanding
> the fact that the plaintiffs were mistaken and that they pointed out their mistake to the defendants immediately and before the defendants had acted on it in any way."<sup>1</sup>

---

I start another example, but same question.

> "The fact that the pursuers had supplied drivers to operate
> the machinery and remove the silt did not demonstrate the existence of a contract on the
> defender’s terms."<sup>3</sup>

Presume I must write out "The fact that" like this.

> The **pursuers**`'` "having supplied drivers to operate
> the machinery and remove the silt did not demonstrate the existence of a contract on the
> defender’s terms."<sup>3</sup>

Now presume I must clarify **pursuers**, "pursuers [who] offered to supply machinery that could be used to remove silt from the
defender’s pond"<sup>4</sup>. Can I write this?

> The **"pursuers [who] offered to supply machinery that could be used to remove silt from the
> defender’s pond"<sup>4</sup>**`'s` "having supplied drivers to operate
> the machinery and remove the silt did not demonstrate the existence of a contract on the
> defender’s terms."<sup>3</sup>

<sup>1</sup>McKendrick. [*Contract Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (2020 9 ed).](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198701985) p 29.
<sup>2</sup> Op. cit. p 28.
<sup>3</sup> Op. cit. p 89.          <sup>4</sup> Op. cit. p 88.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112149/discussion-on-question-by-elaine-nai-can-quotation-marks-be-followed-s).

Answer (score -1):

> The "pursuers [who] offered to supply machinery that could be used to remove silt from the defender’s pond"4's "having supplied drivers to operate the machinery and remove the silt did not demonstrate the existence of a contract on the defender’s terms."3

The sentence needs restructuring:

The pursuers. [who] offered to supply machinery that could be used to remove silt from the defender’s pond, <s>having</s> supplied drivers to **both** operate the machinery and remove the silt **but they/this**[1] did not demonstrate the existence of a contract on the defender’s terms."

[1]They or this depends upon context.

Comment: Please don't "restructuring" sentence. I want know answer to my question, not different question.

Comment: @ElaineNai I would not have suggested restructuring if I had thought it correct.